# Copy Pandas Dataframe to Postgres with odo

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, odo

There is this top python library odo that I would love to use to transfer data from Pandas to my postgres db  . it looks so convenient  but i don't manage to use it  :( .

Has someone an idea what I am missing.  It must be a little thing .....

- Dataframe = df
- username: postgres
- password: password
- host : localhost
- table: table_

So i come with the following  ligne of code :

```python
import odo, pandas 
..... 
odo(df, 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost::mapping_ean_asin')
```

I got the error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: why not use something like pyodbc or sqlalchemy..much easier and lot of comm support

Comment: can also use `psycopg2` which is specific to `postgres`. And really easy to use too.

Comment: With  sqlalchemy I got a probelm with the engine  and I guess  will do it with psycopg2 and insert row by row the data. it  would have been really cool to do it in  one line of code  :)

Comment: You don't need to copy the data row-by-row to Postgres. For bulk loading, just create a file(.csv) from Dataframe and use `copy_expert` function to dump this in Postgres.

Comment: THE MODULE has the same name  as  the FUNCTION  !!!!      SO :  odo.odo(df, 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost::mapping_ean_asin')

Comment: I finally got the job done with copy_expert

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my on question :) !

```python
SQL_STATEMENT = """ COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH
    CSV
    HEADER
    DELIMITER AS ','
"""

my_file = open("/home.........csv")


def process_file(conn, table_name, file_object):
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.copy_expert(sql=SQL_STATEMENT % table_name, file=file_object)
      conn.commit()
      cursor.close()

connection =  psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost'           password='password'")
     try:
           process_file(connection, 'my table', my_file)
     finally:
           connection.close()
```

I would have prefer the a solution in one line with odo but I got an second error.....